# Year duplicate Dimension error in creating Hierarchy SQL Server OLAP cube

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssas

I am new to OLAP development. I am facing the following below issue.

I have an invoice dimension and attributes as  year, month, date  along with others. I would like to create hierarchy for year ->month->Date. while creating the relation ship between invoiceid-->Year-->Month(created key as month+year)-->date

I get duplicate key error for year 2011 while processing the dimension I understand there are duplicate year. I would like to find the correct approach for this issue Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you provide some screenshots from SSAS on how you model your dimension? Also, what is the KeyColumn and NameCOlumn for your Year attribute in your dimension. What result do you get when you select distinct <keycolumn>, <namecolumn> from <tbl> from the underlying source, more than one row for 2011 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to create a hierarchy from `InvoiceID -> Year -> Month -> Date` ? If so, no wonder you are getting it wrong, you should create your hierarchy as `InvoiceID -> Date -> Month -> Year`

Comment: This fixed my issue  thanks a lot. can you please also tell me how to order the dates by  year and then by months  in Descending or asecnding order in dimensions?

Comment: You can specify the ordering in the properties for each dimension attribute. For your month, your keycolumn could be yyyymm, so that it would sort in ascending order properly over years. your date, as a date, should sort by itself just fine. If you have a bigger problem with this, make a question on it and please try to provide some screenshot. Imgur will allow you to quickly make'em.